# React native not picking up android changes

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Just a general question I couldn't quite find an answer for.

I've been developing a react native app and noticed that when I run it on android it works fine. But when I build and run it on ios it doesn't pick up some of my css changes or some features aren't working as expected.

Is there a reason for this or am I missing like some universal package for react-native?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `react-native run-ios` in the command line

Comment: I get this error failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening test.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.